# Can't insert into mysql Auto Increment row from PHP, but can insert manually from phpmyadmin with same statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

So my problem here is that:

I cannot insert into my auto incremented column from my php

```
(unless I set the insert values to: '','','','$postdate','posttime').
```

HOWEVER: When I used the DEBUGGED insert statement below in phpmyadmin, it ran no worries.
Therefore there is something preventing my insertion from my php code.

This is my code:

```
$qinsert    =   "INSERT INTO `post` (text,sender,text_stamp,post_date,post_time) VALUES ('$message','$sender_id','$date','$postdate','$posttime')";
$finsert    =   mysql_query($qinsert);
$postID     =   mysql_insert_id();
```

This is the output from a debugger:

```
 Date: Fri, 29 Mar 2013 11:02:53 -0400
 Sender: User's Name 
Message:
 Message Text
 Attachment: 
 Post-Date: 2013-03-29
 Post-Time: 08:02:55

 Q-INSRT: INSERT INTO `post` (text,sender,text_stamp,post_date,post_time) VALUES ('Message Text','User's Name ','Fri, 29 Mar 2013 11:02:53 -0400','2013-03-29','08:02:55')
  F-INST: 
  Post-ID:
```

Comment: And, are you applying any mysql escape functions?

Comment: I am not, should I be?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
require '../connect.php';
$email = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
preg_match_all("/(.*):\s(.*)\n/i", $email, $matches);

$message    = $matches[1][18];
$message    = str_replace('<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY style="background-color:#ffffff">', '',$message);
$message    = explode('<',$message);
$message    = $message[0];
$sender     = $matches[2][2];
$sender     = explode('<',$sender); 
$sender_id  = $sender[0];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `post` (`text`,`sender`,`text_stamp`,`post_date`,`post_time`) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($message) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($sender_id) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($textdate) . "','$postdate','$posttime')") or die(mysql_error() . "<--There was error processing the query");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you escaping the variables before putting them into the array? I"m not sure if your sample query had the text and username replaced, or that was copy-pasted verbatim. I"m going to assume the later, so look closely at your query:

```
[...] VALUES ('Message Text','User's Name ','Fri, [...]
```

The 'Users's Name' has an apostrophe in the middle of it, so it's breaking the query. Make sure you're running mysql_real_escape_string($variable) on each variable before inserting it into your query.

```
$message_text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message_text']);
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$query = "INSERT INTO table (text, username) values ('$message_text', '$user_name')";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: This didnt work, i acutally got '','','' returned in the debugger when i put that function for each variable

Comment: Have you connected to mysql first using mysql_connect() // mysql_select_db() ?? And made sure the connection was successful?

Comment: I didnt put a debugger for the connection, but i was able to insert blanks in place of the variable form my php code. so thats why I believe the connection is ok

Comment: also, another website is using the same connection just with a differ db name and password so i figure why fix something that isnt broken

Comment: <?php
$liveORlocal = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if($liveORlocal == 'localhost')
 {
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "root";
 $dbpassword = "";
 $dbname = "test"; 
 }
else
 {
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "xxxx";
 $dbpassword = "xxxx*";
 $dbname = "xxxx";
 }
 
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword);
$accessdb = mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your strings, `User's Name` has a single quote in it.  You also shouldn't use `mysql_` functions, they're deprecated.  But if you insist, use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, so something like:

```
$qinsert    =   "INSERT INTO `post` (text,sender,text_stamp,post_date,post_time) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($message) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($sender_id). " ','$date','$postdate','$posttime')";
```

You should probably escape all strings, not just message and sender.

Ideally, you should use PDO instead, like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sth = $dbh->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO post (text,sender,text_stamp,post_date,post_time) VALUES " .
  "(:message, :sender_id, :date, :postdate, :posttime)"
);
$sth->execute(array(
  ':message' => $message,
  ':sender_id' => $sender_id,
  ':date' => $date,
  ':postdate' => $postdate,
  ':posttime' => $posttime
));
```

Comment: This didnt work, i acutally got '','','' returned in the debugger when i put that:

$qinsert = "INSERT INTO `post` (text,sender,text_stamp,post_date,post_time) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($message) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($sender_id) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($date) . "','$postdate','$posttime')";

Comment: Are you calling `mysql_real_escape_string` after connecting to MySQL?  It won't work without a connection.

Comment: yea my connection is good. I can tell because i was able to insert blank records for $message, $sender_id, $date as '','','', as described above

Comment: I've updated my response with PDO syntax.  You really should use that instead of `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Im going to save this as a last resort, but i have a number of mysql functions working for another site i have. I am using the same sytax for this as well, but i cant get it to work :(